# Livewire Validating with multiple models

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to use $this->validate on multiple models. It appears that $this->validate only validates the first $var. Is there any way to use $this->validate for all of the other $vars?

My code:

```
      $validatedData_Class_Date_Bitmapp = $this->validate([
            'Visible_Public' => 'required',
            'Start_8AM' => 'required',
            'DHS_Certified' => 'required',
            'In_Person' => 'required',
            'IL_Class' => 'required'
        ]);
        Class_Date_BitmappModel::create($validatedData_Class_Date_Bitmapp);
        
        $validatedData_Class_LocationModel = $this->validate([
            'Location_Name' => 'required',
            'Max_Students' => 'required'
        ]);
        Class_LocationModel::create($validatedData_Class_LocationModel);
        
        $validatedData_Class_DateModel = $this->validate([
            'Course_ID' => 'required',
            'Date' => 'required'
        ]);
        Class_DateModel::create($validatedData_Class_DateModel);

        $validatedData_Instructor_Model = $this->validate([
            'Instructor_First_Name' => 'required'
        ]);
        InstructorModel::create($validatedData_Instructor_Model);

        $validated_Course_TypeModel = $this->validate([
            'course_type_id' => 'required'
        ]);
        Course_TypeModel::create($validated_Course_TypeModel);


// HOW TO USE $this->validate to validate ALL of the different $validated variables instead of just the top one.
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Why not try and use the `rules` property or method and then validate once.

```
public function rules () {
  return [
            'Visible_Public' => 'required',
            'Start_8AM' => 'required',
            'DHS_Certified' => 'required',
            'In_Person' => 'required',
            'IL_Class' => 'required',
            'Location_Name' => 'required',
            'Max_Students' => 'required',
            'Course_ID' => 'required',
            'Date' => 'required',
            'Instructor_First_Name' => 'required',
            'course_type_id' => 'required'
        ];
}

public function save () {
     $this->validate();

        Class_Date_BitmappModel::create([
            'Visible_Public' => $this->Visible_Public,
            'Start_8AM' => $this->Start_8AM,
            'DHS_Certified' => $this->DHS_Certified,
            'In_Person' => $this->In_Person,
            'IL_Class' => $this->IL_Class
        ]);

        Class_LocationModel::create([
            'Location_Name' => $this->Location_Name,
            'Max_Students' => $this->Max_Students
        ]);

        Class_DateModel::create([
            'Course_ID' => $this->Course_ID,
            'Date' => $this->Date
        ]);

        InstructorModel::create([
            'Instructor_First_Name' => $this->Instructor_First_Name
        ]);

        Course_TypeModel::create([
            'course_type_id' => $this->course_type_id
        ]);

return true;
}
```